# adding a text line and a link button to a GridViewRow

Tags: c#, asp.net

ok so i have this code so  far:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < fajlovi.Length ; i++)
        {
            string filename = fajlovi[i];
            string link = Server.MapPath("~/upload" + "//" + Page.User.Identity.Name) + fajlovi[i];
            LinkButton button = new LinkButton();
            button.Text = "Download";
            button.PostBackUrl = link;
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(i, i, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);



        }
```

now what i need is to add the string filename and the linkbutton button to a row in a GridView. i know that i need to create a GridViewRow and then add that row to the GridView, but i have no idea how to add the elements into the row.

Anyone know how to work with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements must be added to a TableCell, which in turn must be added to the GridViewRow:

```
        // Filename
        string filename = "...";
        Label lbl_filename = new Label();
        lbl_filename.Text = filename;
        // ...

        // Button
        LinkButton button = new LinkButton();
        button.Text = "Download";
        // ...

        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(i, i, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.ColumnSpan = some_columnspan;
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        cell.Controls.Add(lbl_filename); // add control
        cell.Controls.Add(button); // add control
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
```